# Playing MediaStream using AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource vs HTMLAudioElement.srcObject

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, web-audio-api

I'm trying to play MediaStream from remote peer (WebRTC) using Web Audio API. When i attach the stream to `audio` element using `audio.srcObject = stream` it plays ok, but when i try to use AudioContext it does not play any sound at all (I need to avoid `audio/video` HTML tag).

This piece works:

```
<audio controls>
<script>
   const audioEl = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
   audioEl.srcObject = MY_STREAM;
   audioEl.play();
</script>
```

This one does not:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const sourceNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(MY_STREAM);
sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
// Trying even 'audioContext.resume()' after user gesture with no luck
```

What is weird about that is that when `MY_STREAM` is **my micriphone** then it plays nicely for Web Audio API (i hear the feedback from my mic).

So it would suggest that there is something different between microphone MediaStream and the one i get from WebRTC connection but why DOES it play for simple HTML `audio` tag?

Comment: Most probably, you are not generating your AudioContext from an user-trusted event. You need to resume() it in Chrome (rules are somehow stricter for AudioContext than for MediaElements). Also, why can't you use a MediaElement?

Comment: I've tried making `.resume()` after some click but it didn't helped. FWIW AudioContext.state property is `running` all the time (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/state)

Comment: And you can reproduce on different browsers?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome behaves the same

Comment: Interesting... And if you plug an AnalyserNode to `sourceNode`, you get something? Where does the stream comes from? (Thinking out loud: could this be a cross-origin issue?)

Comment: It seems like AnalyserNode is not getting anything from this stream. I'll try to make a reproducable demo with this

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug to me. [Wfm](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/arpo9dbu/) in Firefox.

Comment: @jib I confirm it works in FF and doesn't in Chrome (even after moving all in user-events). Sounds like AudioContext fails to mark the stream as being consumed or something, but the workaround is anyway quite simple, while quite weird: `new Audio().srcObject = mediaStream` is all it needs, no need to even play this MediaElement... https://jsfiddle.net/agmbwzft/ Adam what are the reasons you can't use a MediaElement? And can you double check that it didn't work for you in FF?

Comment: @Kaiido FWIW, this is the code http://plnkr.co/edit/ZlZV5R11Su5CKqLfFyAX?p=preview that tried to achieve the requirement at Chromium. Did not address the `captureStream` part for Firefox yet. The audio plays at Chromium. Not certain that the complete code is that OP is using.

Answer (score 5):

As [demonstrated by @jib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761430/playing-mediastream-using-audiocontext-createmediastreamsource-vs-htmlaudioeleme?noredirect=1#comment96317224_54761430), this is a Chrome bug.
I have opened a [new issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677) to let them know about it.

I thought I found a workaround by simply assigning this MediaStream to the `srcObject` of a dummy HTMLAudioElement,

```
new Audio().srcObject = mediaStream;
```

but somehow, while testing on my localhost it didn't persist in time, while in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmf7qka6/) it does.

I also encountered a lot of other weird behavior while playing around, like different tabs having incidence on others and things like that.

Add to that [other non-fixed bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=882859) in the area that make me think of false positives and all-in-all, I fear there is no proper solution than waiting for them to fix it...

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems like a general webkit issue as i've checked this on Safari and Opera and all suffers the same. Firefox indeed works with jsfiddle

Comment: @AdamSzmyd ah, it works for me on Safari12.0.3 without workaround using a modified version of the html I provided in the crbug (higher browser compat): https://jsfiddle.net/px1ymj90/ So I'd say it's a Blink bug (Opera is unfortunately now just a skin over Chrome), which makes sense since the split occurred before webkit implements anything from the MediaStream/WebRTC API.

Comment: You got response for the bug - It actually suggest me an workaround for the bug and it seems it works: after attaching stream to Web Audio API, attach it also to HTML `audio` element temporary. You can remove the entire `audio` element after that and sound plays nicely through AudioContext!

Comment: @AdamSzmyd that's the workaround I talk about in my answer and in my bug report, but I also found out it is unreliable, as sometimes it will stop working after a few seconds.